# iOS Triple DES encryption generating a different String to Android

Tags: android, ios, tripledes

I utilised TripleDES encryption in my Android app and it returns the expected string as required. However, when implementing the same feature in iOS using CommonCrypto, the returned string is different than what was expected.

```
    public String encrypt(String message, String secretKey) throws Exception {

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
    byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(secretKey.getBytes("utf-8"));
    byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);

    for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
        keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
    }

    KeySpec keySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(keyBytes);
    SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede").generateSecret(keySpec);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    byte[] plainTextBytes = message.getBytes("utf-8");
    byte[] buf = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
    byte[] base64Bytes = Base64.encodeBase64(buf);
    String base64EncryptedString = new String(base64Bytes);

    return base64EncryptedString;
}
```

iOS Code

```
    + (NSData*)transformData:(NSData*)inputData operation:(CCOperation)operation withPassword:(NSString*)password
{
    NSData* key = [self keyFromPassword:password];
    //NSData* iv = [self ivFromPassword:password];
    NSMutableData* outputData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:(inputData.length + kCCBlockSize3DES)];

    size_t outLength;
    CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt(operation, kCCAlgorithm3DES, kCCAlgorithmDES, key.bytes, key.length, nil, inputData.bytes, inputData.length, outputData.mutableBytes, outputData.length, &outLength);


    if (result != kCCSuccess)
        return nil;

    [outputData setLength:outLength];

    return outputData;
}

+ (NSData*)keyFromPassword:(NSString*)password
{
    NSString* key = [password copy];
    int length = kCCKeySize3DES;

    while (key.length < length)
        key = [key stringByAppendingString:password];

    if (key.length > length)
        key = [key substringToIndex:length];

    return [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

+ (NSData*)ivFromPassword:(NSString*)password
{
    NSString* key = [password copy];
    int length = 8;

    while (key.length < length)
        key = [key stringByAppendingString:password];

    if (key.length > length)
        key = [key substringToIndex:length];

    return [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

It may be helpful to note that the key being used is a 20 byte key. I am limited to the 20-byte key. The android app automatically takes care of this limitation with Array.copyOf function, however, despite zero padding and repeating the first characters of the key as the last eight characters, I still cannot replicate the output in iOS.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is something best debugged by looking at the actual memory,  and comparing it to the hex value of the other device, which you can do in iOS at a breakpoint by selecting the variable in the bottom pane of Xcode and choosing "view memory." I would look at the actual hex data of the keys and iv you are using, which should help you find the discrepancy quickly. (Also, I fail to see the number 20 in your code, despite it being a 20 byte key.  Maybe you pass it in as a parameter?)

Comment: Thanks Owen, on closer inspection, using the hex data i realised what was being done on Android, was to strip off the last 4 bytes and repeated the first 8 characters as the last 8 characters. However, I'm still getting a different encrypted string in iOS. I am not using iv as the Android code does not utilise iv as well

Comment: There are multiple encrypting/decrypting free web sites where you can type your key and some plaintext and get cipher text out.  Do that with some sample data, and see which of the two devices puts out the right cipher text, and correct the other device's code.